# Display the multiplied result of two input fields in another field and also using the same code for every other field present on the page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I was working on jQuery and I come across an obstacle. What I am trying to do is that I have three input fields (qty, price, total), and when the user input values in qty and price, then their multiplied answer would show in total column. So far so good.

But, then I added 2 more inputs or rows with same name and id, and when I enter the values of the first one (qty, price), the result is shown in all the fields name output. Now, I know why is that, because I've used name output in the script to show result, I know I can give different names to fields and my code will work but in that I have to write script for every single row, I was hoping to just use one script function and to apply it on every row.

And also how to display the sum of total in grand total?

**Summary**: I want this code to work like an invoice systems like in retail shops

```
<?php

?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="script/script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#price").keyup(function(){
    var a=$("input[name='qty']").val();
    var b=$("input[name='price']").val();
    var r=$("input[name='output']").val(a * b);
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<table style="border:1px solid purple">
    <tr>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr id="test">
    <td><input id="qty" type="text" name="qty"></td>
    <td><input id="price" type="text" name="price"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="output" name="output"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
    <td><input id="qty" type="text" name="qty"></td>
    <td><input id="price" type="text" name="price"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="output" name="output"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
    <td><input id="qty" type="text" name="qty"></td>
    <td><input id="price" type="text" name="price"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="output" name="output"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="grand">
Grand Total:<input type="text" name="gran" id="gran">
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use input field name as array like `qty[]` `price[]` `output[]` and calculate the output based on index

Comment: @DevendraBhandari, how to use indexes of html arrays in jquery?? sorry im a noob..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have used input field name as an array like qty[], price[], and output[] then iterate through each element using jquery each loop and get the value based on index.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<table style="border:1px solid purple">
    <tr>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td>
        <td><input class="price" type="text" name="price[]"></td>
        <td><input class="output" type="text" name="output[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td>
        <td><input class="price" type="text" name="price[]"></td>
        <td><input class="output" type="text" name="output[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td>
        <td><input class="price" type="text" name="price[]"></td>
        <td><input class="output" type="text"  name="output[]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="grand">
Grand Total:<input type="text" name="gran" id="gran">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".price").keyup(function() {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $("input[name='qty[]']").each(function (index) {
            var qty = $("input[name='qty[]']").eq(index).val();
            var price = $("input[name='price[]']").eq(index).val();
            var output = parseInt(qty) * parseInt(price);

            if (!isNaN(output)) {
                $("input[name='output[]']").eq(index).val(output);
                grandTotal = parseInt(grandTotal) + parseInt(output);
                $('#gran').val(grandTotal);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**jsfiddle link:** http://jsfiddle.net/xtj1g7z3/11/

Comment: its not working...i have replaced the javascript code but the output is displayed only in the first one..and i have also copy paste your whole answer and its not working..

Comment: let me create jsfiddle.

Comment: @mastermind: please note that the HTML Devendra has provided you is malformed like yours because of the duplicate ID's. You **MUST** change this.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid i copied the code provided by mastermind. let me fix it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the most important thing wrong with your code is you have duplicate ID's. ID's must be completely unique; one per page. You have the same ID's for rows and the same ID's for inputs. If you want to share the same reference over different elements, use a class.

So, let's start by rewriting the HTML:

```
<tr class="test">
    <td><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td>
    <td><input class="price" type="text" name="price[]"></td>
    <td><input class="output" type="text" name="output[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
    <td><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td>
    <td><input class="price" type="text" name="price[]"></td>
    <td><input class="output" type="text" name="output[]"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="test">
    <td><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty[]"></td>
    <td><input class="price" type="text" name="price[]"></td>
    <td><input class="output" type="text" name="output[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Now, let's try and get jQuery working. You said you didn't know how to use HTML input arrays, so I have avoided that here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // if any of the qty or price inputs on the page change
    $(".qty, .price").change(function() {
        // find parent TR of the input being changed
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

        var a = $row.find(".qty").val();
        var b = $row.find(".price").val();
        var r = $row.find(".output").val(a * b);
    });
});
```

If you then wanted to update the "total" box, you could do something like this:

```
// declare variable outside of loop
var total = 0;

// loop each table row with class .test
$('.test').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    var value = $row.find('.price').val() * $row.find('.qty').val();
    total = total + value;
});

$('#gran').val(total);
```

You can either add that to the function I built above or have it run off an update button, it's up to you.

These are just ideas that may help you, I haven't the time to give you a fully working solution unfortunately. However, I've made this answer a community wiki, so hopefully somebody may come along and improve upon it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Javascript function to loop through your input elements and update the total and grand total elements. 
Call that function on a suitable event such as blur or change. For basic Javascript tutorials, look up basic websites like w3schools or codeacademy. For functionality like these, you cannot get past or accomplish much without picking up basic Javascript or jQuery skills.

Comment: actually i had read all the tutorials of javascript and jquery. im just stuck in my imagination, if its not too much to ask can you give a little hint of code on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like below, it should work

HTML:

```
<tr id="test">
    <td><input id="qty" type="text" name="qty1" class="1"></td>
    <td><input id="price" type="text" name="price1" class="1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="output" name="output1" class="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
    <td><input id="qty" type="text" name="qty2" class="2"></td>
    <td><input id="price" type="text" name="price2" class="2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="output" name="output2" class="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
    <td><input id="qty" type="text" name="qty3" class="3"></td>
    <td><input id="price" type="text" name="price3" class="3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="output" name="output3" class="3"></td>
    </tr>
```

JS:

```
$("input[name^='price']").keyup(function(){
      evaluateTotal($(this).attr('class'))
    });

        function evaluateTotal (value) {
        var a=$("input[name='qty"+value+"']").val();
        var b=$("input[name='price"+value+"']").val();
        var r=$("input[name='output"+value+"']").val(a * b);
        }
```